Kalman gain for control system ($\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, $\mathbf{C}$, $\mathbf{D}$)
I saw many publications with description of kalman matrix gain for system of three matrices ($\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, $\mathbf{C}$) like
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}[n+1] &= \mathbf{Ax}[n]+\mathbf{Bu}[n] \\
\mathbf{y}[n] &= \mathbf{Cx}[n] \\
\end{align}$$
but in general in control theory there is state space system of form with four matrices ($\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, $\mathbf{C}$, $\mathbf{D}$)
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}[n+1] &= \mathbf{Ax}[n] + \mathbf{Bu}[n] \\
\mathbf{y}[n] &= \mathbf{Cx}[n] + \mathbf{Du}[n] \\
\end{align}$$
How would derivation of kalman gain $\mathbf{K}$ (trough matrixes ($\mathbf{R}$, $\mathbf{P}$, $\mathbf{Q}$) look like is that case?
P.S. I know that for Kalman theory there are another matrices designations are common, but I use control-theory ones

It seems that I found solution by myself
look at stochastic control system
$$\begin{align} \tag{1}
\mathbf{x}[n+1] &= \mathbf{Ax}[n]+\mathbf{Bu}[n] + v[n] \\
\mathbf{y}[n] &= \mathbf{Cx}[n] + \mathbf{Du}[n] + e[n] \\
\end{align}$$
where $v[n]$ - corresponding state noise with covariance matrix $\mathbf{Q}$, $e[n]$ - corresponding output variable noise with  covariance matrix $\mathbf{R}$
Introduce state prediction error $\tilde{x}[k] = \hat{x}[k] - x[k]$
And formulate predictor as
$\hat{x}[k+1] = A \hat{x}[k] + B u[k] + \mathbf{K} (y[k] - C \hat{x}[k] - D u[k])$
Then
$\tilde{x}[k+1] = A \hat{x}[k] + B u[k] + \mathbf{K} (y[k] - C \hat{x}[k] - D u[k]) - x[k + 1] = \\ 
= (A - \mathbf{K}  C) \hat{x}[k] + \mathbf{K} y[k] + B u[k] - \mathbf{K} D u[k] - x[k + 1] $
substituting $y[k]$ and $x[k+1]$ from $(1)$ get
$
\tilde{x}[k+1] = (A - \mathbf{K}  C) \hat{x}[k] + \mathbf{K}  C x[k] + \mathbf{K} e[k] - Ax[k] - v[k] = \\
= (A - \mathbf{K}  C) \tilde{x}[k] + \mathbf{K} e[k] - v[k]
$
So prediction error not dependent from B and D matrices
Next derivation for Kalman gain $\mathbf{K}$ and covariance matrix $\mathbf{P}$ are the same that could be found in literature:
$$\begin{align} \tag{2}
\mathbf{K}[k] &= A \mathbf{P}[k] C^T (R + C \mathbf{P}[k] C^T)^{-1} \\
\hat{x}[k+1] &= A \hat{x}[k] + B u[k] + \mathbf{K} (y[k] - C \hat{x}[k] - D u[k]) \\
\mathbf{P}[k+1] &= A \mathbf{P}[k] A^T + Q + \mathbf{K}[k] C \mathbf{P}[k] A^T \\
\end{align}$$
Conclusion existing of $D$ matrix nothing change in calculation of Kalman $\mathbf{K}$ and $\mathbf{P}$ matrixes, changed only predictor formula -- term $\mathbf{K} (y[k] - C \hat{x}[k] - D u[k])$ instead of term $\mathbf{K} (y[k] - C \hat{x}[k])$
P.S
I used old book where in derivation of kalman gain $\mathbf{K}$ used $A$ matrix. In modern literature there is no $A$ matrix in matrix gain  $\mathbf{K}$ iteration. Also iterations of $P[k+1]$ looks bit different. But in whole entity the same
